# how to update database table when session expired in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, session, session-timeout

I'm new in PHP and Codeigniter, by the way how to update database table when session in CI is expired and where I can put the code? I use uniqid in database, it's called token. here is my login table`username, password, level, token, last_login, exp_time`. and I want to change value token=null when session in Codeigniter is expired.

Answer (score 1):

To do this you have to you have to extend `CI_Session`

Create a php file inside application/core/MY_Session.php

```
class MY_Session extends CI_Session {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

function sess_destroy() {

    //write your update here 
    $this->CI->db->update('YOUR_TABLE', array('YOUR_DATA'), array('YOUR_CONDITION'));

    //call the parent 
    parent::sess_destroy();
}

}
```

But it might not always work because your cookie might get expire so CI will not able to get your current session

Comment: Can i get userdata here like user-id before destroying session, i want to update table on base of user...??? How can i achieve it..
it always returns 0