# Codeigniter update custom table in sess_expiration time

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I set a time for sess_expiration in config file and Codeigniter will expire the sessions and log out the users after that time, but I need to update a table before logging out or destroying sessions.so please help.

[image: Set Expire time for session]

Comment: Have you tried this?  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21908953/how-to-update-database-table-when-session-expired-in-codeigniter

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: you created ci_session table??

Comment: no i just create my own custom table

Comment: checke this https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks every body, I found my question answer.

In session library in system folder I update my table before destroying session.

```
  function sess_destroy()
  {
    // Kill the session DB row

    if ($this->sess_use_database === TRUE &&  isset($this->userdata['session_id']))
    {
        $this->CI->db->where('session_id', $this->userdata['session_id']);
        $this->CI->db->delete($this->sess_table_name);
    }

    // Kill the cookie
    setcookie(
                $this->sess_cookie_name,
                addslashes(serialize(array())),
                ($this->now - 31500000),
                $this->cookie_path,
                $this->cookie_domain,
                0
            );

    // Kill session data
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kabul");
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->load->model('tsm/tsm_model');
    $CI->tsm_model->update_session('3',0);


    $this->userdata = array();
}
```

[image: codeigniter session destroy and update a table before that]